# Dump global datas to disk in assembly code

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, memory-dump

The experiment is on Linux, x86 32-bit.

So suppose in my assembly program, I need to periodically (for instance every time after executing 100000 basic blocks) dump an array in .bss section from memory to the disk.  The starting address and size of the array is fixed. The array records the executed basic block's address, the size is 16M right now.

I tried to write some native code, to `memcpy` from .bss section to the stack,  and then write it back to disk. But it seems to me that it is very tedious and I am worried about the performance and memory consumption, say, every-time allocate a very large memory on the stack...

So here is my question, how can I dump the memory from global data sections in an efficient way? Am I clear enough?

Comment: Why not call _fwrite and point it at the data in your .BSS with a pointer as a calling argument on the stack?

Comment: Why assembly code? Looks like [application checkpointing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_checkpointing). Consider using [BLCR](http://crd.lbl.gov/departments/computer-science/CLaSS/research/BLCR/)

Comment: Copying to the stack makes no sense.  You can make `write(2)` system calls on anything.  Copying yourself isn't going to be any faster than letting the kernel do it during `write(2)`.  Slower, in fact, as the kernel still has to copy your data for `write(2)`, unless you use zero-copy I/O on the copy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, **don't write this part of your code in asm**, esp. not at first.  Write a C function to handle this part, and call it from asm.  If you need to perf-tune the part that only runs when it's time to dump another 16MiB, you can hand-tune it then.  System-level programming is all about checking error returns from system calls (or C stdio functions), and doing that in asm would be painful.

Obviously you *can* write anything in asm, since making system calls isn't anything special compared to C.  And there's no part of any of this that's easier in asm compared to C, except for maybe throwing in an `MFENCE` around the locking.

Anyway, I've addressed three variations on what exactly you want to happen with your buffer:

1. Overwrite the same buffer in place (`mmap(2)` / `msync(2)`)
2. Append a snapshot of the buffer to a file (with either `write(2)` or probably-not-working zero-copy `vmsplice(2)` + `splice(2)` idea.)
3. Start a new (zeroed) buffer after writing the old one.  `mmap(2)` sequential chunks of your output file.

### In-place overwrites

If you just want to overwrite the same area of disk every time, `mmap(2)` a file and use that as your array.  (Call `msync(2)` periodically to force the data to disk.)  The mmapped method won't guarantee a consistent state for the file, though.  Writes can get flushed to disk other than on request.  IDK if there's a way to avoid that with any kind of guarantee (i.e. not just choosing buffer-flush timers and so on so your pages usually don't get written except by `msync(2)`.)

### Append snapshots

The simple way to append a buffer to a file would be to **simply call `write(2)` when you want it written**.  `write(2)` does everything you need.  If your program is multi-threaded, you might need to take a lock on the data before the system call, and release the lock afterwards.  I'm not sure how fast the write system call would return.  It may only return after the kernel has copied your data to the page cache.

If you just need a snapshot, but all writes into the buffer are atomic transactions (i.e. the buffer is always in a consistent state, rather than pairs of values that need to be consistent with each other), then you don't need to take a lock before calling `write(2)`.  There will be a tiny amount of bias in this case (data at the end of the buffer will be from a slightly later time than data from the start, assuming the kernel copies in order).

IDK if `write(2)` returns slower or faster with direct IO (zero-copy, bypassing the page-cache).  `open(2)` your file with with `O_DIRECT`, `write(2)` normally.

There has to be a copy somewhere in the process, if you want to write a snapshot of the buffer and then keep modifying it.  Or else MMU copy-on-write trickery:

### Zero-copy append snapshots

There is an API for doing zero-copy writes of user pages to disk files.  Linux's [`vmsplice(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/vmsplice) and [`splice(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/splice) in that order will let you tell the kernel to map your pages into the page cache.  Without `SPLICE_F_GIFT`, I assume it sets them up as copy-on-write.  (oops, actually the man page says without `SPLICE_F_GIFT`, the following `splice(2)` will have to copy.  So IDK if there is a mechanism to get copy-on-write semantics.)

Assuming there was a way to get copy-on-write semantics for your pages, until the kernel was done writing them to disk and could release them:

Further writes might need the kernel to memcpy one or two pages before the data hit disk, but save copying the whole buffer.  The soft page faults and page-table manipulation overhead might not be worth it anyway, unless your data access pattern is very spatially-localized over the short periods of time until the write hits disk and the to-be-written pages can be released.  (I think an API that works this way doesn't exist, because there's no mechanism for getting the pages released right after they hit disk.  Linux wants to take them over and keep them in the page cache.)

I haven't ever used vmsplice, so I might be getting some details wrong.

If there's a way to create a new copy-on-write mapping of the same memory, maybe by `mmap`ing a new mapping of a scratch file (on a tmpfs filesystem, prob. `/dev/shm`), that would get you snapshots without holding the lock for long.  Then you can just pass the snapshot to `write(2)`, and unmap it ASAP before too many copy-on-write page faults happen.

### New buffer for every chunk

If it's ok to start with a zeroed buffer after every write, you could `mmap(2)` successive chunk of the file, so the data you generate is always already in the right place.

- (optional) `fallocate(2)` some space in your output file, to prevent fragmentation if your write pattern isn't sequential.
- `mmap(2)` your buffer to the first 16MiB of your output file.
- run normally
- When you want to move on to the next 16MiB:

  1. take a lock to prevent other threads from using the buffer
  2. `munmap(2)` your buffer
  3. `mmap(2)` the next 16MiB of the file *to the same address*, so you don't need to pass the new address around to writers.  These pages will be pre-zeroed, as required by POSIX (can't have the kernel exposing memory).
  4. release the lock

Possibly `mmap(buf, 16MiB, ... MAP_FIXED, fd, new_offset)` could replace the `munmap` / `mmap` pair.  `MAP_FIXED` discards old `mmap`ings that it overlaps.  I assume this doesn't mean that modifications to the file / shared memory are discarded, but rather that the actual mapping changes, even without an `munmap`.

Comment: Thank you Peter! I really appreciate your answer!!

Answer (score 1):

Two clarifications for *Append snapshots* case from Peter's answer.

**1. Appending without `O_DIRECT`**

As Peter said, if you don't use `O_DIRECT`, `write()` will return as soon data was copied to page cache. If page cache is full, it will block until some outdated page will be flushed to disk.

If you are only appending data without reading it (soon), you can benefit from periodically calling [`sync_file_range(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sync_file_range.2.html) to schedule flush for previously written pages and [`posix_fadvise(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/posix_fadvise.2.html) with `POSIX_FADV_DONTNEED` flag to remove already flushed pages from page cache. This could significantly reduce the posibility that `write()` would block.

**2. Appending with `O_DIRECT`**

With `O_DIRECT`, `write()` normally would block until data is sent to disk (although it's not strictly guaranteed, see [here](https://lwn.net/Articles/348739/)). Since this is slow, be prepared to implement you own I/O scheduling if you need non-blocking writes.

The benefits you could archive are: more predictable behaviour (you control when you will block) and probably reduced memory and CPU usage by collaboration of your application and kernel.