# How to write to a binary file using the fastest way possible for Linux?

Tags: c, linux, file, binaryfiles, file-writing

I'm working on a C project where we have to write some binary files in a Embedded Linux environment (2.6.37). Normally we are able to write the files in something like 200-300 ms, but eventually the file take up to 10 seconds to be written and we have no idea why - the occurrence is quite randomic with no special event happening in other parts of the system, such as in the UI app.

Either way we are revising or method to write to the file and doing some research on the web ([here](/q/23178191) and [here](/q/11563963) and [here](/q/10195343)) we concluded that writing using native Linux code would be better then doing it pure C even though that may not end up helping much with our problem. For now we are writing in a way **similar to this, that is, with these functions**:

```
#include <stdio.h>
const unsigned long long size = 8ULL*1024ULL*1024ULL;
unsigned long long a[size];

int main()
{
    FILE* pFile;
    pFile = fopen("file.binary", "wb");
    for (unsigned long long j = 0; j < 1024; ++j){
        //Some calculations to fill a[]
        fwrite(a, 1, size*sizeof(unsigned long long), pFile);
    }
    fclose(pFile);
    return 0;
}
```

Well what I would like to know is *which would be the native Linux way to do an equivalent operation* (and in the fastest way possible)? The links mentioned only tell about *copying* files, not simply writing to them, so I suppose there might be more specific functions to be used.

Any help appreciated (as well as any tip regarding the original problem).

Comment: What happens with your "bare bones" version? If it works well, the problem lies somewhere else. BTW I don't see why you need `unsigned long long j` for a loop that only reaches `1024`.

Comment: It's hard to say without details but I'd bet the problem is not the file writing method but something else as I can't imagine how that could take 10s.

Comment: @WeatherVane that code was copy-and-pasted from one of the links I linked; the idea was to show only the principle, the functions being used for writing the file. So just ignore this detail :)

Comment: Why pass `1` as the `size` argument to `fwrite()`? Anyone used to `stdio.h` would expect `fwrite(a, sizeof *a, size, pFile)` and wonder why you've done it differently.

Comment: It's supposed to be MCVE that demonstrates the problem http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve , and another aside, your array `a[]` is more than 64 mB is this a problem in embedded?

Comment: @WeatherVane I understand your complain, but in fact there is no way for me to write a MCVE for my current code - lots of intricacies and it wasn't even me who wrote it. Anyway I did say in the text that was just an example of the functions currently being used - and that was only the context; the real question is about writing using Linux functions...

Comment: Could it write in parallel? Is there a file locking? Could it have a deadlock? Could that calculation be more than just calculation? How long could that calculation take? What is the device? Is it really a local file system?

Comment: @olivecoder thanks for the tips; I'll see with the team.

Comment: Sorry! Just now I can see that you are writing 8Gb files! So if it the device is something slow like a SD probably it is flushing the writing buffer files when taking longer. How often are you writing those 8Gb? Have you tested this with the code above? If this is the case you have two options: write less or replace the device for a faster one.

Comment: What happens to your page cache as you write the file?  What happens to the page cache when writing the file gets really slow?  Does the problem go away if you write using direct IO?  Does the problem stop if you drop cache occasionally?

Comment: Are you using virtual memory? Could you turn the swap off?

Comment: 8 billion items at 8 bytes/items with 8 bits/byte = 512 gigabits. Writing 512 gigabits in 0.2 seconds means that you have a write bandwidth of 2.5 terabits/second. That's absurdly fast, especially for an embedded system. I don't believe you at all, unless you're building an embedded super-computer.

Comment: Can you tell us what data sizes are involved, the amount of RAM you have, and what device you're writing to? I ask because "the fastest way possible" is to allocate all the data in nonswappable RAM and write it in a single `write` system call to a raw device, but you may not have the hardware to support that.

Comment: @user3386109, it's likely the OP is conducting timing runs without calling `sync` afterwards (so just measuring write to memory, at least in part).  I've made that mistake myself before!

Comment: It sounds like "forget about doing this". Or an XY-problem.

Comment: @TobySpeight I'd say it's worse than that. Assume that you're just writing data to DRAM, and the DRAM has a 64-bit bus. The DRAM would have to be running at 40GHz to sustain a rate of 2.5 terabits/second. There is no DRAM that runs at 40GHz and no processor that can write to DRAM at that speed. With current technology, you would need a DRAM bus that's 1024 bits wide to sustain a data rate of 2.5 terabits/second.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31458381/dump-global-datas-to-disk-in-assembly-code *In theory*, the fastest options are using either `splice()` or `O_DIRECT` (what is "faster" depends on your use-case, i.e. where your data comes from). As for `O_DIRECT`, it's quite difficult to implement your code properly (so that it will be at least not slower than normal writes), and in a rare best case (when you constantly writing more and more data sequently to a non-fragmented fs) the benefit is no more than `5-10%` (in my experience).

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you are writing to an SD Card or micro Sd Card.  Not all card are created equally.  Start with the fastest you can find.  I recommend the SanDisk Extreme Pro.  They claim to be able to store up to 90Mbits a second.

Two, your, "randomic" comment gives rise to the SD Card possibly doing a load balance.  The card actually has a small cpu inside that will do storage reallocation based on sector hits.  They do this to elongate the life of the sd card.

If you write a small amount to an sd card it goes to an internal buffer of ram on the sd card itself.  Usually they are sized at 512 bytes per block.  Sometimes they have multiple blocks of these, "caches" resulting in higher throughput.  This gives excellent performance for small file sizes.  Also, note that 512.  If you can match your writes to be in chunks of 512 you are matching the fastest possible way to transfer to the underlying medium.  I.E. never write less than that size ;-)